# How to mass-replace variable string in database?

Tags: mysql, replace

I need to mass-replace a string in my forum database via `phpMyAdmin`, but I don't know how.

I want to replace:

```
[member=1]username[/member]
```

with

```
[url=https://www.website.xxx/index.php?action=profile;u=1]username[/url]
```

My problem is with that `"1"`, which changes with each `username`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
UPDATE messages
SET body = replace(body,"[member=","[url=https://www.website.xxx/index.php?action=profile;u=")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a MySQL installed here
but I read up it works there as well, as Phil said, you need regex

To read about [regex replace, go here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)
To check how it works, [go here](https://regex101.com/) and paste what you need to find and replace.

Although it is not clear what part exactly you want to replace

The whole thing with number after '='
`[member=ANY_NUMBER]username[/member]`
**or** replace the ANY_NUMBER with
`[...]username[/url]`?

If you need to replace the whole thing
use this regex `\[member=\d\]username\[\/member\]`
the `\d` is a number, but only one, if it is multiple digits, do `\d+`

so it would be

```
UPDATE messages 
SET body = 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(body, 
    '\[member=\d+\]username\[\/member\]', 
    'REPLACE_WITH_TEXT_HERE'
  )
```

Before actually updating, *do run a select to verify it works as intended*

if you need to replace the ANY_NUMBER part for anything else
so it would be

##### Warning: db engines can reference capture groups differently, so check with select that it works before doing an `update`

```
UPDATE messages 
SET body = 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(body, 
    '(\[member=)\d+(\]username\[\/member\])', 
    '\1REPLACE_WITH_TEXT_HERE\2'
  )
```

The `\1` and `\2` are important and are called capture groups, we can divide a search in parts and use that as we want, for ex do `\2\1` to reverse order.

Before actually updating, *do run a select to verify it works as intended*

### UPDATE:new information

> eliminate everything but the username, i.e., change this: [member=ANY_NUMBER]username[/member] to this: username.

That is a subset of described up there

So we need to find `[member=ANY_NUMBER]username[/member]`
and get only the `username`
I strongly advise you to look up what regex is, how to use it to replace and how to use captive groups.

This is regex to 'select' user from body
`\[member=\d+\](.+)\[\/member\]`

How it works? It finds anything that looks like `[member=ANY_NUMBER]`
then it looks to find `[/member]`, and ANYTHING in between is captured by a capture group `(.+)` it literally says here: any sting of any chars of any length.

This is how it works:
[link to what you see](https://regex101.com/r/HSd2WA/1) https://regex101.com/r/HSd2WA/1
[image: how it works image]

update SQL:

```
UPDATE messages 
SET body = 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(body, 
    '\[member=\d+\](.+)\[\/member\]', 
    '\1'
  )
```

### VERIFYING THAT IT WORKS

How? Do a select, that's how!

I created a table with ID and body, populated with what you can find in the regex link.

```
 id |                             body
----+---------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | sdfdfsfdsasfda[member=1]merof[/member]safdfdsafdsfdsa
  2 | sfdafdsafdsa[member=10]Fraga Campos[/member]sfdasfda
  3 | asdffdsafdsa[member=300]Campos[/member]afsfdsafds
  4 | dfsvnosringtpoeringer[member=10000]Fraga[/member]sdafdsdfgdfg
  5 | dsfggfdsgfds[member=10000]dude[/member]
  6 | sdgf[member=10000]user[/member]sfd
  7 | dfg[member=10000]00)_09824;sd-2=3#_@$JFuser[/member]df
(7 rows)
```

Now I do a select
the `'!!!\1!!!'` is there replace value, where `\1` is capture group, I added `!!!` for it to be easier to see.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(body, 
    '\[member=\d+\](.+)\[\/member\]', 
    '!!!\1!!!'
  )
from messages
```

Gives me

```
                regexp_replace
----------------------------------------------
 sdfdfsfdsasfda!!!merof!!!safdfdsafdsfdsa
 sfdafdsafdsa!!!Fraga Campos!!!sfdasfda
 asdffdsafdsa!!!Campos!!!afsfdsafds
 dfsvnosringtpoeringer!!!Fraga!!!sdafdsdfgdfg
 dsfggfdsgfds!!!dude!!!
 sdgf!!!user!!!sfd
 dfg!!!00)_09824;sd-2=3#_@$JFuser!!!df
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, merof.
Given I don't understand all the nuances of the code and I don't want to mess with the database, what I would like to do is this:
eliminate everything but the username, i.e., change this:
[member=ANY_NUMBER]username[/member]

to this:

username.

I thought of doing this in two steps, first replacing [member=ANY_NUMBER] with a space (or nothing) and then do the same with [/member]. I hope this was more clear.

Comment: You should be more explicit and provide an example data for answers to be more on point, I could've written 1/3 of it ended up to be.
do read up on regex, it sometimes saves you hours of work

Comment: I don't think the command is efficient.
Here's what happens when I do a select: https://i.imgur.com/icsS3fu.png

Comment: That's what happens when there is no data to work on.
Please add at least three example entries.
as for `efficient`, I think you mean `does not do the thing`
first, as I can see there's some edge cases, and, more importantly, what engine is it?
MySql?

Comment: The server has 10.3.38-MariaDB with PHP: 7.4.33. I'm trying to make this change with phpMyAdmin. I used this code in phpMyAdmin and it changes many, many strings where there's not even a username or member strings. For example: "[size]." becomes "[siz1l]." - "Oi, povo. :good:" becomes "Oi, povo. :goo1>T+", etc. So, it seems something is not working. :(